# Tires coming off OR Tires falling off?

Tags: grammar

My kid loves to watch this kind of videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzoH0yKN3hM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1qzWboZAFs

So how would a local say that tires are coming off? I'd like to stick to a phrase that I can use every day.

- Tires falling off of the truck
- Tires flying off of the truck
- Tires taking off of the truck
- Tires coming off of the truck

OR

- Tires falling off the truck
- Tires flying off the truck
- Tires taking off the truck
- Tires coming off the truck

Thank you.

Comment: It takes considerable effort to answer these questions, so a reaction would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, one would describe these tires (at least in the first video) as:
coming off or coming off of the truck.

Things fall off surfaces of some kind. OR They fall off a thing due to how they are attached. The doll's arms fell off when it hit the floor. The books fell off the table.

Tires might fall off a truck (as in the back of a pick-up truck) but not wheels coming off (as in coming loose) a truck.

Fly off is metaphorical and just means at great speed. So, in the cartoon, you could say the tires flew off the truck, though in real life, that really doesn't happen, unless again, they flew off the back of a truck.

The best bet here is come off, but fly off is okay for a cartoon as they do indeed look like they are flying off of it.

Comment: Thank you Lambie. This is very helpful.

Comment: Do I use "come off" or "come off of"? What is the difference?

Comment: Tires can come off of something. The tires came off their axles. But, that happens when a mechanic removes them, unscrews them.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused. I'd like to picture it. Maybe I should re-phrase my question, what is the difference of "tires came off the truck" versus "the tires came off of the truck". In the first video, should I just stick with "tires came off the truck"?

Comment: There is no real difference: They are the same here.

Comment: Thank you so much. That would be all for this question.